# How to compare every row of dataframe to dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, row, tidyverse

I want to get the number of values that are equal to every other row in dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(1, 1, 5, 1),
  b = c(2, 3, 2, 8),
  c = c(2, 6, 2, 2)
)
```

desired output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b     c desired_column
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>        
1     1     2     2 <dbl [4]>     
2     1     3     6 <dbl [4]>     
3     5     2     2 <dbl [4]>     
4     1     8     2 <dbl [4]>
```

[image]

In the column "desired_column":
firt row: 3, 1, 2, 2:

3: is because the first row has the same three values compared to itself

1: is because there is one value with the same value in both rows and same column (first and second):

[image]

2: There are two values that are equal in first and third row and same column :

[image]

2: There are two values that are equal in first and fourth row and same column :

[image]

The second, third and fourth row of "desired_column" are results of the same process:
The `i`th number in the result is the number of values in common between the current row and the `i`th row

Comment: I don't understand why in the result, the first row first number is `3` ("same three values compared to itself), but the 4th row (input `1, 8, 2`) has a `2` as the first result number. There are no repeated values in row 4, so why is the first result number 2?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. The `i`th number in the result is the number of values in common between the current row and the `i`th row!

Comment: The 2 as the first result number in desired_column's fourth row is because when you compare row 4 (1, 8, 2) and row 1 (1, 2, 2), there are only two values that are in both rows: 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this: in short, with each row of the dataframe, duplicate it to create a new dataframe with all values changed to that row, and compare that dataframe with the original (whether the values are the same). `rowSums` of each of that comparison will give you the vectors you want.

```
# Create the desired output in list 
lst <- 
  lapply(1:nrow(df), function(nr) {
     rowSums(replicate(nrow(df), df[nr, ], simplify = FALSE) %>% 
             do.call("rbind", .) == df)})

# To create the desired dataframe
df %>% tibble(desired_column = I(lst))
```

In `tibble` call in the last row, `I()` is used to put in list output as a column.

Answer (score 3):

My approach was to join the data to itself, to make a table comparing each value to the values of that column in each original row. Then we count the matches and pivot wider again.

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid) -> df2

left_join(df2, df2, by = "name") %>%
  count(rowid.x, rowid.y, wt = value.x == value.y) %>%     # Edit - shorter
  pivot_wider(names_from = rowid.y, values_from = n) %>%
  nest(desired_column = c(`1`:`4`)) %>%
  select(-rowid.x) -> matches

bind_cols(df, matches)


# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b     c desired_column  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>          
1     1     2     2 <tibble [1 × 4]>
2     1     3     6 <tibble [1 × 4]>
3     5     2     2 <tibble [1 × 4]>
4     1     8     2 <tibble [1 × 4]>


> matches %>%
+   unnest(cols = c(desired_column))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     3     1     2     2
2     1     3     0     1
3     2     0     3     1
4     2     1     1     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make a function using a couple of for loops:

```
count_combs <- function(df){
output <- list()
vector <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
  vector[j] <- sum(df[i,] %in% df[j,])
}
output[[i]] <- vector
}
return(output)
}

df$desired_column<- count_combs(df)
```

Here the count_combs function counts the combinations of each row iterated once by i and again by j, summing up each time the row elements are %in% the comparison row.